# Passing sensitive information from one component and other component

Tags: security, communication, distributed-system

There are two components to interact and the user id is passed from one component to other to track the record of the user activity. However , the cyber team informed the user id should not be passed  between the systems. Any thoughts to accommodate the requirement without bypassing cyber team's concern?